# Configure apache mod-vhost-alias

Tags: apache2, mod-vhost-alias

I was wondering if you could use a wildcard in the VirtualDocumentRoot directive. I mean is it possible to scan multiple directories with the VirtualDocumentRoot, like multiple home directories to look for sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use of wildcards in the `VirtualDocumentRoot` directive is not possible using Apache 2.2.3.

A correct VirtualHost entry for HTTP requests looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *
    UseCanonicalName Off
    LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log vcommon
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/shared/%0
    VirtualScriptAlias  /var/www/vhosts/shared/%0
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

This will serve a request to `subdir.mydomain.com` from the directory `/var/www/vhosts/shared/subdir.mydomain.com`

To serve HTTPS requests too, duplicate this and replace `*:80` with `*:81`

Comment: Hey Andy, I am running 2.2.14 on Ubuntu 10.04 - and using this code if I get a request to ANY subdomain, will it forward it to http://domain.com/subdomain ?

Comment: @iUsable That sounds like you've got `mod_proxy` or an `.htaccess` rewrite involved, although it could be to do with the order of directives in your `httpd.conf`. You'd be better asking in a fresh question with more detail, link to it here and I'll have a look.